# Moderation with higher-order factor - SEM

Tags: interaction, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

My colleague and I are wondering if we could use a product-indicators approach to compute moderations if the moderator is an higher-order factor.

So my question is, how can I run a moderation with an higher-order factor as the moderator variable?

We used the **indProd::semTools** function in the past when doing moderations with first order factor but it doesn't sound correct to me to do the same with an higher-order factor.

Thank you very much,

Santiago